# What mathematics indicate that the vacuum of the universe is metastable?

Tags: cosmology, vacuum, higgs, bosons

As I understand it, the meta stability of the universe's vacuum depends on the electroweak force, which depends on the mass of the top quark and the Higgs boson. But I don't understand this fully. Can someone explain the mathematics and the science behind why the mass of the Higgs boson indicates that the universe is metastable? All of the explanations that I find online are too simplified. I'd like something in-depth.

Comment: This thesis is a good resource: https://dash.harvard.edu/handle/1/40050090

Comment: See the wiki on the subject https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum_decay. Especially the section on "Electroweak vacuum decay." It's well written and in-depth and has lots of links.